# Spring Websocket Plugin return value

Tags: grails, spring-websocket

I'm using the [Spring Websocket Plugin](https://github.com/zyro23/grails-spring-websocket/tree/v1.1.0) and I want to send some logging-output to the client.

Here is my Code:

```
@MessageMapping("/run")
@SendTo("/topic/run")
protected String run(@Payload WebForm form) {
      doSomeWithForm(form)
    return "started"
}
```

GSP:

```
    $(function () {
        var socket = new SockJS("${createLink(uri: '/stomp')}");
        var client = Stomp.over(socket);

        client.connect({}, function () {
            client.subscribe("/topic/run", function (message) {
                $("#log").append(message.body);
            });
        });
        $("#submitBtn").click(function() {
            client.send("/app/run", {}, JSON.stringify({
                'type':$("#type").val(),
                'id':$("#id").val()
            }));
        });
    });
```

This works well so far, but message.body looks like this `""This my return text""`.

Why are there two "? How can I extract this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try `JSON.parse(message.body)`.

note: that behavior will change with grails-2.5/grails-3.0 shipping spring-4.1+. from that spring version on, plain String payloads will not be json-encoded anymore, meaning then the `message.body` in your js code will have the string value without double quoting